# How to Rename Column name using cassandra table

Tags: cassandra, rename

I have a question in cassandra db. I want to rename the column name. But its showing syntax error. Because my column name contain space. So how can I change column name:

Ex: `sample column` into `samplecolumn`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Whenever you ask question always include what you did? what error you get properly so our community can help you better you should also read our guide https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Good luck

Answer (score 8):

You can use alter table to rename a column but theres a lot of restrictions on it. As sstables are immutable in order to change state of things on disk everything must be rewritten.

> The main purpose of RENAME is to change the names of CQL-generated primary key and column names that are missing from a legacy table. The following restrictions apply to the RENAME operation:
>
> - You can only rename clustering columns, which are part of the primary key.
> - You cannot rename the partition key.
> - You can index a renamed column.
> - You cannot rename a column if an index has been created on it.
> - You cannot rename a static column (since you cannot use a static column in the table's primary key).

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/alter_table_r.html